# Easiest Way of Returning a Table for manual completion

Tags: sql

I have a situation where periodically I am doing the following:

- New data comes in about a business
- The new data gets joined on several look-up tables (such as mapping employees to teams, firm names to industries)
- As the business is changing, new employees or firms can appear each time new data is loaded, at which point my current code adds the new occurences to the existing look-up tables and then i export the table, manually type in the mappings (manually is the easiest way), and then re-import the table

I was wondering if there is an easier way on the fly to write 'directly' into a table as it were rather than having to save and re-import it as i am currently doing. (Also please let's assume that its just easier for me to manually think about and type the mappings in rather than having a `CASE` statement or similar to do the task)

Comment: Are you familiar with `UPDATE` and `INSERT`?

Comment: But if i have 40 nulls lets say i'd rather just go through in an excel format and type in each field manually to complete them?